# Remove nested git repository

Tags: java, git, repository, gitlab

I have a folder structure like so:

```
root
|--client
|--server
pom.xml
```

I have initiated the root folder, but when pushing the files to the repository the client folder does not get pushed.

Instead it only has an annotation of `client @ abc191ls91` and I cannot enter that specific folder from the repository (using gitlab).

I am suspecting some kind of submodules, but I cannot find any file named `.gitmodules` so I am a bit clueless of how to handle this issue.

Anyone has an idea of what might be the issue here?

Comment: So, do you have a `.git` directory only for your root directory, or for each sub-directory (client and server)?

Comment: I only have a git directory for the root directory. There was a .git directory for the client file (due to autogenerated vue app) but when I deleted it from disk I got this issue...

Comment: Have you added the client directory to git? Is the client directory empty?

Comment: I'm using `git add .` so I expect it to add the client folder as well as all other files. The folder is not empty – but my Tower app (git gui) does not track the changes made to those specific files...

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue, have you tried using the git console?

Comment: The problem was a "faulty" setup of the client folder as a submodule. I deleted the entire folder and created it again, then it started tracking everything correctly.

Comment: Glad you could solve the problem. I would recommend you answer your own question so it will not be listed under _unanswered_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by deleting the entire folder & re-creating it. Now it is tracked correctly by git.